# Handling scala array group with ties

Tags: scala

I have an array of names. I need to group by elements and select the name with highest count. If there are ties, then return the alphabetically last name. I have the below so far:

```
val names = Array("Adam", "Eve", "Adam", "Eve", "John", "Doe")
val countNames = names.map(x => (x, names.count(_ == x))).toSeq.sortBy(_._2)
```

My result should be Eve. How can I get that?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use the natural ordering of a `(Int, String)` tuple, and get the *last* element:

```
scala> names.map(x => (names.count(_ == x), x)).sorted.last._2
res0: String = Eve
```

This would work as expected because this ordering would put the highest count last, and among tuples with same count would sort alphabetically, again placing "higher" alphabetical values last.

p.s. the grouping can also be done using `groupBy`:

```
names.groupBy(identity) // Map(Adam -> Array(Adam, Adam), Doe -> Array(Doe), Eve -> Array(Eve, Eve), John -> Array(John))
  .mapValues(_.length)  // Map(Adam -> 2, Doe -> 1, Eve -> 2, John -> 1)
  .toSeq.map(_.swap)    // ArrayBuffer((2,Adam), (1,Doe), (2,Eve), (1,John))
  .sorted               // ArrayBuffer((1,Doe), (1,John), (2,Adam), (2,Eve))
  .last._2              // Eve
```

Comment: I like your first approach. I did not know that "sorted" sorts both elements of the tuple.

Comment: Use `max` instead of `sorted.last`.

Answer (score 2):

Define a lexicographical order, where the count has priority over the string. Then use it to sort your list and pick the first element:

```
 countNames.sortWith( (x,y) =>
                       (x._2 > y._2) ||
                       (x._2 == y._2 && x._1 > y._1)  )(0)._2
```